# Existing libs showed error when trying opencv in JNI on Eclipse

Tags: windows, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I tried to learn how to use opencv in JNI part of my Android application, when I include the OpenCV.mk from the right directory in my Android.mk , it gave me out some errors:

```
i686-linux-android-g++: error: contrib: No such file or directory
i686-linux-android-g++: error: legacy: No such file or directory
i686-linux-android-g++: error: ml: No such file or directory
i686-linux-android-g++: error: stitching: No such file or directory
i686-linux-android-g++: error: objdetect: No such file or directory
i686-linux-android-g++: error: ts: No such file or directory
i686-linux-android-g++: error: videostab: No such file or directory
i686-linux-android-g++: error: calib3d: No such file or directory
i686-linux-android-g++: error: photo: No such file or directory
i686-linux-android-g++: error: video: No such file or directory
i686-linux-android-g++: error: features2d: No such file or directory
i686-linux-android-g++: error: highgui: No such file or directory
i686-linux-android-g++: error: androidcamera: No such file or directory
i686-linux-android-g++: error: flann: No such file or directory
i686-linux-android-g++: error: imgproc: No such file or directory
i686-linux-android-g++: error: core: No such file or directory
```

I've checked the OpenCV.mk and it says in line 10

OPENCV_LIBS_DIR:=$(OPENCV_THIS_DIR)/../libs/$(OPENCV_TARGET_ARCH_ABI)

the directory really exists

why this? My OpenCV4Android version is 2.4.6, NDK r8e, here is my Android.mk and Application.mk   OS: windows 7 64 bit

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include E:/workspace/Android/OpenCV/OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
include $(OPENCV_MK_PATH)

LOCAL_MODULE    := ImgFun
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ImgFun.cpp  

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ldl
LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(OPENCV_LIBS)

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

---

```
APP_STL:=gnustl_static  
APP_CPPFLAGS:=-frtti -fexceptions  
APP_ABI:= x86
APP_PLATFORM := android-14
```

---

If you have some ideas,  please let me know either here or learningpro.dong@gmail.com, thank you in advance

Comment: Solved now by myself.
remove the line LOCAL_LDLIBS += $(OPENCV_LIBS)  in Android.mk and it will work well.
May this can help someone :)

Comment: You can add how to solve it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @Learningpro Don't add Solved to the title. Don't give solution in comments. Make an answer.